# Oracle - Create or Replace View - preserving the comments on the columns

Tags: oracle

I have a view with some fixed number of columns. These columns are specified with comments.

Now I change the view sql (some where conditions) using the "create or replace" (not manually, some business logic of my java application changes this view sql)

The view gets created, and working fine. But the only problem is that all the comments added to the columns are all lost.

Though I understand we are rewriting the ddl of the view, is there a way to preserve the comments even after the sql change?

Comment: If you get into the habit of always editing the source code (that you have checked into source control, of course) and only deploying changes that way, you can include the comments in the same source file so that whenever it is changed, the view comments are re-added.

Answer (score 5):

`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` will create ... or replace the view. That is, there is an implied `DROP VIEW` on it¹.

If you need to change some *constraints* on your view without dropping it entirely you probably need [`ALTER VIEW`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4004.htm) instead. However, you can't use it to change the *definition* of your view.

In your particular case, as you need to update the `WHERE` clause, maybe an alternate option would be to have some kind of master view with all relevant columns and *comments* -- but without the `WHERE` clause. And have an other view on top of it which add only the `WHERE` clause. That way you only have to *replace* that second-level view when you need to update it.

---

¹ As noticed by *be here now* in a comment bellow, this is a little bit over simplified as *"privileges are preserved after `create or replace`". To quote [the relevant part of the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm#sthref5420)(emphasis mine):

> Specify **`OR REPLACE`** to re-create the view if it already exists. You can use this clause to change the definition of an existing view **without dropping, re-creating, and regranting object privileges** previously granted on it.
>
> **`INSTEAD OF`** triggers defined in the view **are dropped** when a view is re-created.

Comment: this is not exactly an implied `drop view`. privileges are preserved after `create or replace`, though `instead of` triggers (as the doc says) and, apparently, comments are not

Comment: @beherenow Yes, you are perfectly right the privileges are preserved. I probably should have mentioned it. This is now fixed. Thank you for your comment.